# How to use the pre-trained ResNet50 in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to design a network built on the pre-trained network with tensorflow, taking Reset50 for example.  [ry released a model](https://github.com/ry/tensorflow-resnet), however, I don't know how to use it to build my model with their checkpoint? The definition of resnet can be found in resnet.py. who can help me? Thank you very much!

```
def inference(x, is_training,
          num_classes=1000,
          num_blocks=[3, 4, 6, 3],  # defaults to 50-layer network
          use_bias=False, # defaults to using batch norm
          bottleneck=True):
c = Config()
c['bottleneck'] = bottleneck
c['is_training'] = tf.convert_to_tensor(is_training,
                                        dtype='bool',
                                        name='is_training')
c['ksize'] = 3
c['stride'] = 1
c['use_bias'] = use_bias
c['fc_units_out'] = num_classes
c['num_blocks'] = num_blocks
c['stack_stride'] = 2

with tf.variable_scope('scale1'):
    c['conv_filters_out'] = 64
    c['ksize'] = 7
    c['stride'] = 2
    x = conv(x, c)
    x = bn(x, c)
    x = activation(x)

with tf.variable_scope('scale2'):
    x = _max_pool(x, ksize=3, stride=2)
    c['num_blocks'] = num_blocks[0]
    c['stack_stride'] = 1
    c['block_filters_internal'] = 64
    x = stack(x, c)

with tf.variable_scope('scale3'):
    c['num_blocks'] = num_blocks[1]
    c['block_filters_internal'] = 128
    assert c['stack_stride'] == 2
    x = stack(x, c)

with tf.variable_scope('scale4'):
    c['num_blocks'] = num_blocks[2]
    c['block_filters_internal'] = 256
    x = stack(x, c)

with tf.variable_scope('scale5'):
    c['num_blocks'] = num_blocks[3]
    c['block_filters_internal'] = 512
    x = stack(x, c)

# post-net
x = tf.reduce_mean(x, reduction_indices=[1, 2], name="avg_pool")

if num_classes != None:
    with tf.variable_scope('fc'):
        x = fc(x, c)

return x
def stack(x, c):
for n in range(c['num_blocks']):
    s = c['stack_stride'] if n == 0 else 1
    c['block_stride'] = s
    with tf.variable_scope('block%d' % (n + 1)):
        x = block(x, c)
return x


def block(x, c):
filters_in = x.get_shape()[-1]

m = 4 if c['bottleneck'] else 1
filters_out = m * c['block_filters_internal']

shortcut = x  # branch 1

c['conv_filters_out'] = c['block_filters_internal']

if c['bottleneck']:
    with tf.variable_scope('a'):
        c['ksize'] = 1
        c['stride'] = c['block_stride']
        x = conv(x, c)
        x = bn(x, c)
        x = activation(x)

    with tf.variable_scope('b'):
        x = conv(x, c)
        x = bn(x, c)
        x = activation(x)

    with tf.variable_scope('c'):
        c['conv_filters_out'] = filters_out
        c['ksize'] = 1
        assert c['stride'] == 1
        x = conv(x, c)
        x = bn(x, c)
else:
    with tf.variable_scope('A'):
        c['stride'] = c['block_stride']
        assert c['ksize'] == 3
        x = conv(x, c)
        x = bn(x, c)
        x = activation(x)

    with tf.variable_scope('B'):
        c['conv_filters_out'] = filters_out
        assert c['ksize'] == 3
        assert c['stride'] == 1
        x = conv(x, c)
        x = bn(x, c)

with tf.variable_scope('shortcut'):
    if filters_out != filters_in or c['block_stride'] != 1:
        c['ksize'] = 1
        c['stride'] = c['block_stride']
        c['conv_filters_out'] = filters_out
        shortcut = conv(shortcut, c)
        shortcut = bn(shortcut, c)

return activation(x + shortcut)


def bn(x, c):
x_shape = x.get_shape()
params_shape = x_shape[-1:]

if c['use_bias']:
    bias = _get_variable('bias', params_shape,
                         initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
    return x + bias


axis = list(range(len(x_shape) - 1))

beta = _get_variable('beta',
                     params_shape,
                     initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
gamma = _get_variable('gamma',
                      params_shape,
                      initializer=tf.ones_initializer)

moving_mean = _get_variable('moving_mean',
                            params_shape,
                            initializer=tf.zeros_initializer,
                            trainable=False)
moving_variance = _get_variable('moving_variance',
                                params_shape,
                                initializer=tf.ones_initializer,
                                trainable=False)

# These ops will only be preformed when training.
mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(x, axis)
update_moving_mean = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(moving_mean,
                                                           mean, BN_DECAY)
update_moving_variance = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(
    moving_variance, variance, BN_DECAY)
tf.add_to_collection(UPDATE_OPS_COLLECTION, update_moving_mean)
tf.add_to_collection(UPDATE_OPS_COLLECTION, update_moving_variance)

mean, variance = control_flow_ops.cond(
    c['is_training'], lambda: (mean, variance),
    lambda: (moving_mean, moving_variance))

x = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, mean, variance, beta, gamma, BN_EPSILON)
#x.set_shape(inputs.get_shape()) ??

return x


def fc(x, c):
num_units_in = x.get_shape()[1]
num_units_out = c['fc_units_out']
weights_initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(
    stddev=FC_WEIGHT_STDDEV)

weights = _get_variable('weights',
                        shape=[num_units_in, num_units_out],
                        initializer=weights_initializer,
                        weight_decay=FC_WEIGHT_STDDEV)
biases = _get_variable('biases',
                       shape=[num_units_out],
                       initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
x = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(x, weights, biases)
return x


def _get_variable(name,
              shape,
              initializer,
              weight_decay=0.0,
              dtype='float',
              trainable=True):
"A little wrapper around tf.get_variable to do weight decay and add to"
"resnet collection"
if weight_decay > 0:
    regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(weight_decay)
else:
    regularizer = None
collections = [tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, RESNET_VARIABLES]
return tf.get_variable(name,
                       shape=shape,
                       initializer=initializer,
                       dtype=dtype,
                       regularizer=regularizer,
                       collections=collections,
                       trainable=trainable)


def conv(x, c):
ksize = c['ksize']
stride = c['stride']
filters_out = c['conv_filters_out']

filters_in = x.get_shape()[-1]
shape = [ksize, ksize, filters_in, filters_out]
initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=CONV_WEIGHT_STDDEV)
weights = _get_variable('weights',
                        shape=shape,
                        dtype='float',
                        initializer=initializer,
                        weight_decay=CONV_WEIGHT_DECAY)
return tf.nn.conv2d(x, weights, [1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')


def _max_pool(x, ksize=3, stride=2):
return tf.nn.max_pool(x,
                      ksize=[1, ksize, ksize, 1],
                      strides=[1, stride, stride, 1],
                      padding='SAME')
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically you should use the code supplied for the model. You can create graph using them and then supply the checkpoint file, see how to do it in case of ResNet50 below:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.slim.nets import resnet_v1
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim

# Create graph
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, height, width, channels])
with slim.arg_scope(resnet_v1.resnet_arg_scope()):
    net, end_points = resnet_v1.resnet_v1_50(inputs, is_training=False)

saver = tf.train.Saver()    

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, '.resnet_v1_50.ckpt')
    representation_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('resnet_v1_50/pool5:0') # if you don't know names like these, consider referring to corresponding model file or generate .pbtxt file as mentioned in  @civilman628 's answer in link below
    img = ...  #load image here with size [1, 224,224, 3]
    features = sess.run(representation_tensor, {'Placeholder:0': x})
```

For more details, please see my (@parthg) answer on Tensorflow Github issue related to this: [#7172](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7172)

Answer (score 4):

I use keras which uses TensorFlow. Here is an example feeding one image at a time:

```
import numpy as np

from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications import resnet50

# Load Keras' ResNet50 model that was pre-trained against the ImageNet database
model = resnet50.ResNet50()

# Load the image file, resizing it to 224x224 pixels (required by this model)
img = image.load_img("path_to_image.jpg", target_size=(224, 224))

# Convert the image to a numpy array
x = image.img_to_array(img)

# Add a forth dimension since Keras expects a list of images
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

# Scale the input image to the range used in the trained network
x = resnet50.preprocess_input(x)

# Run the image through the deep neural network to make a prediction
predictions = model.predict(x)

# Look up the names of the predicted classes. Index zero is the results for the first image.
predicted_classes = resnet50.decode_predictions(predictions, top=9)

print("This is an image of:")

for imagenet_id, name, likelihood in predicted_classes[0]:
    print(" - {}: {:2f} likelihood".format(name, likelihood))
```